# how to generate the localhost URL by executing a node js file?

Tags: node.js

I wrote a program of node js on Brackets Text Editor and saved it with name first.js. When I am executing it with command prompt using -
node first.js

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(req,res)
{
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.write('hello js');
    res.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
```

It is running fine but when I am trying to run it on the localhost, it is not working.

The program that I wrote was -

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "trying to run it on the localhost". When I run it and then make an HTTP request to it, I get the expected output. You should probably provide more information about what precisely you are doing to test making a request to this server (e.g. what software you are using, what URL you are entering into it, etc).

Comment: Have you tried this url including the port? http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

If you did try localhost:8080 and that still doesn't work, it could be that some other program is running on that port. Try .listen(3000) then visit localhost:3000.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can create a simple http server using express (be sure that u have the packaged installed , you can install express using npm : npm install express) .

your server.js code is :

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
console.log("response");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server listining on port ", port);
});

lets say you save this file in c:/folder , open cmd in the same folder
run : node server.js .
now go to your browser and check : http://localhost:4000/
```